# What's the difference between jsp and jsi?

Tags: java, javascript, html, jsp, jakarta-ee

I have noticed that .jsi and .jsp files work almost the same way. So what is their purpose and how to use them correctly? in which situation to use which one?

Comment: :) I know right? This thing totally bums me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that '.jsi' files are fragments of JSPs that are designed to be included in other JSPs using the JSP include mechanism.

The reason for the different suffix is to prevent the files from accidentally being compiled (or validated) as if they were complete JSPs.

Comment: is there really no other reason? and are compilers really implemented that way?

Comment: Well, yes.  If you have a JSP fragment in your webapp in a file with suffix ".jsp", and someone sends request with the corresponding URL, then the JSP compiler will attempt to compile it.  It has to.  It has no way of knowing that the file is not a full JSP.  For JSP validators, it is even worse ...

Comment: so you mean that if i hit the url pointing to a jsi file on my system, the broswer will not display it?